# How to handle TabControl Tab closed in MVVM design patterns for WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a TabControl

```
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemsViewModelCollection}" 
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabControlTemplateSelector}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding OpenedTab, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- this is the header template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

Each tab are rendered with the Header Text and then a close button. (not sure why there are a close button when i only have specified a textblock in the template).

But when i click the close button debugger breaks. How will i handle the clossing of a tab correctly. I have a ObservableCollection with TabViewModels.

Comment: You can try to use mvvm light library with event to command trigger, check for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868589/mvvm-light-adding-eventtocommand-in-xaml-without-blend-easiery-way-or-snippet

Comment: What do you mean by `debugger break`? Did it throw some error?

Comment: Ye it throw some error. Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead

Comment: Are you removing the `Tabs` from the `TabControl.Items` or the `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I have not added any logic. Just pressed the X on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was using https://github.com/MahApps and it had some modified styles for TabControl that i have overlooked, meaning there was added a click action.

Overwriting the style solved the problem.