# MVVM Light - Event to Command & ListView - SelectedItem

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

I have looked all over for an answer to this with no luck. I'm using MVVM Light and I have a ListView in one of my views. I would like to find a way to fire a command when the selected item in my ListView is clicked using the 'Event to Command' built into MVVM Light. At this point, I have no clue how to go about doing this. Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

From my GameView.xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Adventurers}"
              Name="AdvListView"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
              Background="Gray"
              BorderBrush="Transparent"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Grid.Row="2">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowAdvCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,
                                          ElementName=AdvListView}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Level" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Level}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I'm not entirely sure where in the ListView the EventToCommand should go. Also, I understand that this code is completely incorrect.

From GameViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand ShowAdvCommand { get; private set; }
ShowAdvCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteShowAdvCommand(), () => true);

private void ExecuteShowAdvCommand()
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Firing");
}
```

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868589/mvvm-light-adding-eventtocommand-in-xaml-without-blend-easiery-way-or-snippet)

Comment: Perhaps subscribing to the SelectionChanged instead of the Clicked event would work. Please explain what is supposed to wrong about the command code.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd That worked. If you'd like to propose that as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XAML you are subscribing to the `Clicked` event. Change to the `SelectionChanged` event  to make sure there is a SelectedItem.

A click on the ListView will not always select an item.

Comment: One last thing, how might I access that selected item in code (the associated viewmodel to be specific)?

Comment: The Command will part of the ViewModel, so `this` will refer to the ViewModel. If you are interested in the SelectedItem, you are passing it as the parameter but you could also add a dependency property to the ViewModel and bind that to the SelectedItem property of the ListView. If you do that you can access the selected item by accessing the dependency property.

Comment: Everything seems to be in line now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Good! No problem, that's what we're here for :)