# Without Interactivity.dll: Alternative to MVVMLight's EventToCommand

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

In our current C# project, we use the `MVVM light` framework and its `EventToCommand` feature to bind events to commands (as also mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868589/)).
We use it for example like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <cmd:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SelectTree}"
                            Command="{Binding Path=SelectTreeGotFocusCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**My question is**: What is the easiest way to achieve the same behaviour (i.e., `EventToCommand`, not limited to `GotFocus`) without using `System.Windows.Interactivity`?

To avoid the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), here is some background:

- We are developing an addon for an already existing main application, on which we do not have any influence. Our addon is served as a dll which is used by this main application.
- So far, we used XAML code as given above (i.e., using `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `EventToCommand`). However, the last release of the main application contains an old version of `System.Windows.Interactivity` (so far, it was not included at all) which doesn't support this.
- This means that using the old `Interactivity.dll` will cause our addon to be non-functional. However, overwriting the dll with the new version we need will cause issues with parts of the main application.
- I read about using two different versions of the same dll in a project (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll)) but this seems to be quite involved. Since there are only a few places we use this construction, I thought that replacing it with code not using `Interactivity.dll` might be easier.

Comment: You could find it in [MvvmLight source](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and take the relevant part alone?

Comment: The issue is that they require the `Interactivity` functionality

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to the **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf** nuget package and change your namespace declarations to

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

you can use the `InvokeCommandAction` like so:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus"}">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="..." CommandParameter="..."/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```