# Wpf Mouse event set on canvas, but targets child object

Tags: wpf, events, canvas

I have a `Canvas` that contains a `Rectangle`. On that canvas, I bind a mousedown event to a command on the ViewModel. In that command, I am being passed the `MouseEventArgs`, but there the Target element is either the `Canvas` or the `Rectangle`. Where can I find in the `MouseEventArgs` the `Canvas` this event was fired from?

My code is more or less:

```
<Canvas Background="White">
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <local:InteractiveCommand Command="{Binding CmdMouseLeftButtonDown}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" />
</Canvas>
```

And in the ViewModel:

```
ICommand CmdMouseLeftButtonDown => new DelegateCommand<MouseEventArgs>(e => 
{
    e.??? // <= Where do I find the Canvas here, whether I click on the Rectangle or Canvas?
}
```

Please do not answer with some hackish solution like `e.MouseDevice.Target.Parent`. This needs to work however complicated the element in the canvas is. It could contain another canvas for instance.

Answer (score 1):

A view model is not supposed to have a reference to a UI element such as a `Canvas` or a `Rectangle` at all in the first place. This effectively breaks the MVVM pattern and that's why it makes no sense to pass the `sender` argument to the command.

You might as well get rid of the `EventTrigger` and invoke the command programmatically from the code-behind of the view:

```
<Canvas Background="White" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
</Canvas>
```

---

```
private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var yourViewModel vm = DataContext as YourClass;
    vm.CmdMouseLeftButtonDown.Execute(sender as Canvas); //<-- pass the Canvas as a command argument or create a new command argument type that holds a reference to the Canvas
}
```

This is certainly not any worse than your current approach as far as the MVVM pattern is concerned. You are still invoking the very same command from the very same view and MVVM is not about eliminating code. It is about separation of concerns.

Comment: If a ViewModel is not supposed to use the MouseEventArgs, how am I to make a control that uses the position of the mouse on the canvas? For instance if I make a custom control that's a X-Y input pad. Where does the code is supposed live? I can't any f-ing tutorial that makes any sense. I'm loosing my mind with this stupid wpf f-ing garbage.

Comment: I guess you didn't even try my suggestion then? It should be pretty simple to implement.

Comment: I want to do it right. In my understanding, if mvvm was consistent, I should be able to bind the mouse position from xaml to a ViewModel property. Something like `<Canvas><Mouse Position="{Binding Blah, Mode=OneWayToSource} /></Canvas>`but of course that doesn't exist.

Comment: No, you can't bind the current mouse position to a source property.

Comment: what do you think about this answer, is that the right way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047415/how-do-i-get-mouse-positions-in-my-view-model

Comment: Yes, if you want to pass a Point to the VM. I am not sure how this related to your original question about the Canvas though. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, perhaps then the event will have a proper Source property... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your `MouseEventArgs.Source` will reference to the `Canvas` in any case but the `MouseEventArgs.OriginalSource` will referece to the `Rectange` if you have clicked on its area. It will be the control determined by pure hit testing.

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: Yes, Source, OriginalSource, Target, everything is pointing to the Rectangle when I click it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `<Canvas Background="Transparent" ... />`

as answered in the following question by @Rob Fonseca-Ensor:

[WPF: Canvas mouse events not firing on empty space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507165/wpf-canvas-mouse-events-not-firing-on-empty-space)