# Bind event in MVVM and pass event arguments as command parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I wanted to bind an event with ViewModel.

I used

> clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity

and i used trigger for the same

```
  <Canvas Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="InteractiveCanvas" Style="{StaticResource canvasChartStyle}" ClipToBounds="True" >
        <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
            <intr:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="AppointmentEditing" />
            </intr:EventTrigger>
        </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
```

but I need event arguments to be used. Here am not able to get the same.

In wpf any possiblity is there to bind event and get event arguments ?  With out ussing MVVM lite or PRISM.

I just want to get the event arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVVM Passing EventArgs As Command Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter)

Comment: Would using CommandParameter be enough ?

Comment: with CommandParameter  , how we can bind event argument with CommandParameter

Comment: Why do you need to use `EventArgs` in your view model?

Comment: @MikeEason I wanted to get mouse position, whether any alternative is there for same ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by adding the DLL's:

- `System.Windows.Interactivitiy`
- `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`

In your XAML:

Use the CallMethodAction class.

Use the `EventName` to call the event you want; then specify your `Method` name in the `MethodName`.

```
<Window>
    xmlns:wi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">

    <wi:Interaction.Triggers>
        <wi:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ei:CallMethodAction
                TargetObject="{Binding}"
                MethodName="ShowCustomer"/>
        </wi:EventTrigger>
    </wi:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

In your ViewModel Code:

```
public void ShowCustomer()
//The method must be public & can take 0 parameters or 2 parameters i.e.
//object sender & EventArgs args
{
    // Do something.
}
```

P.S: This is a real late response to the question but I hope it helps you.

Comment: This works without the need to add another library just to get the event arguments.

Comment: @hfann: May i ask how? Because the Interaction.Triggers, EventTrigger & CallMethodAction are  apart of the aforementioned assemblies.

Comment: When I referred to a libaray, I meant MVVMLight or Prism. I'm already using System.Windows.Interactivityu DLL already.

Comment: Which effectively means one would require to use the DLL's mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Should using CommandParameter ..It's all :)

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="InteractiveCanvas" Style="{StaticResource canvasChartStyle}" ClipToBounds="True" >
        <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
            <intr:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AppointmentEditing}" CommandParameter="YourParameters" />
            </intr:EventTrigger>
        </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: But how we can pass mouseeventargs as parameter ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter. This should help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the MVVM-Light framework. Their implementation of EventToCommand includes a PassEventArgsToCommand option.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868589/mvvm-light-adding-eventtocommand-in-xaml-without-blend-easier-way-or-snippet), and [this old blog post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2009/11/bug-correction-in-messenger-and-new-feature-in-eventtocommand-mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha/) from Laurent Bugnion for more details.

Comment: I cant use any framework here, whether any pure WPF idea could you suggest ?

Comment: What's wrong with using a framework? Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? The best I can suggest is to download the MVVMLight source code and copy the relevant class (EventToCommand.cs) into your own library - https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: @VisakhVA yes using  PassEventArgsToCommand="True", you must chage a litle be your command then.